# INSERT across Databases in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, cross-database

I'm trying to do an INSERT from one database to another, eg:

```
//called in database 'model'
INSERT INTO login.Hospital (name, phonenumber) --EDIT, now Hospital
VALUES ('Foo Bar', '555-555-5555');
```

I get this error:

```
"null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint"
```

Where column id is a primary key on table People that auto-increments.

Is there a reason PG won't auto-increment id when doing an insert cross-database? Is there a 'recommended' way around this?

Thank you.

--EDIT-- 
**For clarification**: 
I have 2 databases, model and login each with a schema of dbo. Login has a schema called login which is for a Foreign Data Wrapper. 
The goal is from my database: model, call a Login database table using the schema login for tables we've imported (eg INSERT INTO login.hospitals... etc)

For all intents and purposes this Hospital table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE People(ID SERIAL NOT NULL, name TEXT, phonenumber TEXT);
```

I hope this clarifies any issues.

Comment: in postgres "login" willbe schema, not database. It is different from Mysql... try running `\dt+ login.people` in `psql` it will shouw you the structure of table

Comment: You're correct it would be schema, but I know the structure of the table, I need to INSERT cross-schema.

Comment: please update answer with result of my command - it will show why you have an error

Comment: This is the result of your command: http://i.imgur.com/2EMvgIp.jpg
Yes, you will note the table name is different than the example I gave above.

Comment: Since the company I work for does not have any mysql databases, nor have I ever used mysql myself, I do not think I am running it on mysql instead of postgres.

Comment: I think @VaoTsun meant `\d+` (not `\dt+`), which will display the columns in the table and their definitions, as well as any constraints and indexes.

Comment: Here is the result with that modification: http://i.imgur.com/kfCtNQj.jpg

Comment: yeah - my bad. `\dt+` must be fro schemas?..

Comment: So what do you mean? Databases or schemas? That makes a big difference. And please [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement for `login.people`

Comment: Added the edit, please see additional information above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While searching I discovered these solutions:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/26654.1380145647%40sss.pgh.pa.us
http://www.slideshare.net/jkatz05/developing-and-deploying-apps-with-the-postgres-fdw

These essentially involve creating a foreign table and maintaining two tables, something I wanted to avoid.

So, my solution was to create a trigger on the source DB (eg Login) for each table that is called from the calling DB (eg Model). This trigger would be fired *before* an INSERT and call a trigger function. The trigger function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.tf_insert_cross_schema()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    sequenceName TEXT = 'dbo.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_id_seq';

BEGIN
    IF (NEW.id IS NULL) THEN
        NEW.id = (SELECT nextval(sequenceName));
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE;
```

Thanks!